# dial tcp 10.1.0.35:8080: connect: connection refused in docker desktop

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop

I'm deploying a simple application image which has readiness, startup and liveness probes through docker desktop app. I tried to search for similar issues but none of them matched the one which I'm facing therefore created this post.

Image : rahulwagh17/kubernetes:jhooq-k8s-springboot

Below is the deployment manifest used.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jhooq-springboot
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jhooq-springboot
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jhooq-springboot
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: springboot
          image: rahulwagh17/kubernetes:jhooq-k8s-springboot

          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "512m"
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "512m"

          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080

          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /hello
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            periodSeconds: 10

          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /hello
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            periodSeconds: 10

          startupProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /hello
              port: 8080
            failureThreshold: 60
            periodSeconds: 10

          env:
            - name: PORT
              value: "8080"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jhooq-springboot
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: jhooq-springboot
```

After deploying, pods status is CrashLoopBackOff due to Startup probe failed: Get "http://10.1.0.36:8080/hello": dial tcp 10.1.0.36:8080: connect: connection refused

```
  Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From                     Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----                     -------
  Normal   Scheduled  <unknown>                                       Successfully assigned default/jhooq-springboot-6dbc755d48-4pqcz to docker-desktop
  Warning  Unhealthy  7m22s (x7 over 8m42s)  kubelet, docker-desktop  Startup probe failed: Get "http://10.1.0.36:8080/hello": dial tcp 10.1.0.36:8080: connect: connection refused
  Normal   Pulled     6m56s (x4 over 8m51s)  kubelet, docker-desktop  Container image "rahulwagh17/kubernetes:jhooq-k8s-springboot" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    6m56s (x4 over 8m51s)  kubelet, docker-desktop  Created container springboot
  Normal   Started    6m56s (x4 over 8m51s)  kubelet, docker-desktop  Started container springboot
  Warning  BackOff    3m40s (x19 over 8m6s)  kubelet, docker-desktop  Back-off restarting failed container
```

Comment: Can you check the container logs, or try to listen to `0.0.0.0` host

Comment: Checked the logs but didn't find any error.
```
2022-08-24 10:52:09.009  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.jhooq.Jhooqk8s.JhooqK8sApplication   : Starting JhooqK8sApplication on jhooq-springboot-6dbc755d48-4pqcz with PID 1 (/app.jar started by root in /)
2022-08-24 10:52:09.123  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.jhooq.Jhooqk8s.JhooqK8sApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
```
@ĐàoMinhHạt